# Redirecionamento de URL Com Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Eu quero colocar no meu projeto acessar uma página em um subdiretório de *views*. Tipo `views/pessoa/criar.jsp`.

Como posso escrever um *controller* que acesse essa página?

Estou usando Spring MVC 3 e `InternalResourceViewResolver`.

Tentei com *redirect* e não consegui.

Comment: No return do seu controller é só por o nome do jsp que você quer que seja chamado. Olha essa pagina aqui: http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/spring-mvc/#11-5-a-logica-ola-mundo

Comment: A minha resposta conseguiu ajudar você?

Answer (score 1):

No retorno do *controller*, se já estiver tudo configurado corretamente - `/WEB-INF/views/` como prefixo e .jsp como sufixo - é só você retornar `"pessoa/criar"`.

Comment: Creio que você trocou... `.jsp` é o sufixo e `/WEB-INF/views/` é o prefixo, não?

Answer (score 1):

Vou colocar dois métodos de um controller contendo as formas mais comuns de fazer isso.

Em código seria algo nessa linha:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getdata() {
    List<String> list = getList();

        //return back to index.jsp
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        model.addObject("lists", list);

        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/listagem", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listagem() {
        return "listagem";
    }
}
```